# How to solve dconf-WARNING **: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site'

Tags: ubuntu-studio, dconf

Some cli programs on ubuntu studio (like flatpak) print out this warning:

```
dconf-WARNING **: 06:52:56.776: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/site”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling (https://live.gnome.org/dconf), I found out:

"dconf is a low-level configuration system. Its main purpose is to provide a backend to GSettings on platforms that don't already have configuration storage systems."

Maybe this file was not created because the ubuntu studio (20.10) is KDE based? Or it is a oversight?

Anyway, I did find no reason to not create the dconf database, so I did:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
sudo dconf update
```

The file /etc/dconf/db/site was created and flatpak is now working without printing the message.

**OBS:** This may not work if your linux system is using multiple [dconf profiles](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-profiles.html.en)

Look into the directory */etc/dconf/profile* and if it has more than one file you need to create a file with the same name and a directory with an ".d" in the directory */etc/dconf/db* for every file present in */etc/dconf/profile*

For example:

```
~ ᐅ ls /etc/dconf/profile
distro site
```

The are two files, *distro* and *site* in the directory.

In this case, you need to execute:

```
sudo touch /etc/dconf/db/site
sudo touch /etc/dconf/db/distro
sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/site.d
sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/distro.d
sudo dconf update
```

Comment: Thank you. I faced the same problem and your solution works very well for me.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: This solution did not work for me until I first followed the directions in [Create /etc/dconf/db/site and /etc/dconf/db/distro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458858/create-etc-dconf-db-site-and-etc-dconf-db-distro?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Updated the information for your case as well