# Create /etc/dconf/db/site and /etc/dconf/db/distro

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dconf

I am getting the following error from `dconf` upon login to my Ubuntu 22.04 dell precision 5570 workstation:

```shell
Error found when loading /etc/profile

# unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file "/etc/dconf/db/site": open() failed: No such file or directory: expect degraded performance
# unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/distro': Failed to open file "/etc/dconf/db/distro": open() failed: No such file or directory: expect degraded performance

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

I have tried following the steps found in this askubuntu question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1397206/268697

However, when I run `sudo dconf update` it does not create the `/etc/dconf/db/site` or `/etc/dconf/db/distro` files. This appears to be causing some issues with my session once logged.

Interestingly this only appears to happen when I enable a proprietary nvidia driver via Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers (Currently have nvidia-driver-525 enabled).

I've looked around elsewhere and am not really finding anything to resolve this issue. Is this a known bug or is there a known fix that I'm just not finding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed the error presenting on reboot with the following:

```shell
sudo touch /etc/dconf/db/site
sudo touch /etc/dconf/db/distro
sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/site.d
sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/distro.d
sudo dconf update
```

Not sure if there was supposed to be configuration written to these, so not sure this is a fix so much as a bandaid.

Comment: Thanks… I have also searched for a resolution to this issue to no avail, but your "solution" also worked for me.