# Unable to install Dell firmware upgrade

Tags: upgrade, dell, ubuntu-studio, firmware

I'm running a Dell desktop with Ubuntu Studio 22.04 installed as a fresh install.  For about a month or so, I've seen a notification in the upgrader for a Dell firmware update.  However, it does not install.  I ran fwupdmgr and got the following output:

```
(fwupdmgr:81595): dconf-WARNING **: 08:27:43.495: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/site”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
Command not found
```

I looked `/etc/dconf/db/site` and saw that this directory does not exist; however, `/etc/dconf/db/site.d` does exist.  Any suggestions as to how I can implement this upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

According to a German forum https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/dconf-warnungen/, the command

```
sudo dconf update
```

from package `dconf-cli` should create `/etc/dconf/db/site`. This package might need to be installed as it is not installed by default in (specific versions of) Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: Duplicate of this question and answered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397205/how-to-solve-dconf-warning-unable-to-open-file-etc-dconf-db-site -- From that answer, 'dconf-cli' was not a default install for Studio, and had to be installed first.